# Trying to access variables from another class

Tags: c++

Im having an issue getting my variable from my original class to print in another class method
Quick example of my issue:

say the variable was declared here in the test.h file:

```
class player{
private:
int x = 10;
void setX(); //method for setting X from user input
int getX(); //Method for retrieving variable
}
```

Then in another class method where i want to print X

```
 class inTheWoods{
 public:
 printInfo();
 }
```

test.cpp file:

```
void player::setX(){
cout << "Set X to a number:" << endl;
cin >> x
}

int player::getX(){
return x;
} 


int inTheWoods::printInfo(){
player playerObj; //Player object to access methods in player class
cout << playerObj.getX();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(){
inTheWoods woodsObj;
woodsObj.printInfo();
return 0;
}
```

Whenever I run my program that resembles this problem the int does not display correctly and throws me a strange negative number. I hope this isnt too much code and that I documented everything correctly

Comment: `player` has no constructor, so the members of `playerObj` get unpredictable values.

Comment: `player playerObj; //Player object to access methods in player class` you create a new local variable of type player. Then don't do anything with it.  I expect it will print 10.

Comment: @PeteBecker How would I use a constructor in this case. They kind of confuse me

Comment: @drescherjm That was my object I created so that I could access methods from that class. Unless this is the wrong way to go about it

Comment: If you want to do something useful with your player object you should not be creating local variable in inTheWoods::printInfo().

Comment: I copied your code and few basic fixes (make `getX()` public, add semicolon to `cin` and at end of 2 classes, return type for `printInfo()`, it worked as is. https://pastebin.com/QZcSnRBa

Comment: @Aditya Thank you for this code but I am trying to keep the methods in their own .cpp and not in main.cpp

Answer (score 1):

If you want the classes to be in a separate files, it should still work:

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "inTheWoods.h"


int main()
{
    inTheWoods woodsObj;
    woodsObj.printInfo();
    return 0;
}
```

**Player.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class Player
{
    int x = 10;
    void setX();
public:
    int getX();
};
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "Player.h"

void Player::setX()
{
    std::cout << "Set X to a number:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x;
}

int Player::getX()
{
    return x;
}
```

**inTheWoods.h**

```
//#pragma once
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>

class inTheWoods
{
public:
    void printInfo();
};
```

**inTheWoods.cpp**

```
#include "inTheWoods.h"

void inTheWoods::printInfo()
{
    Player playerObj; //Player object to access methods in player class
    std::cout << playerObj.getX();
}
```

`#pragma once` is a preprocessor that prevents multiple includes, in case you didn't know. You can choose to skip it (Visual Studio auto-generated the file with the line).

---

In summary, these are the changes I needed to make from your implementation:

1. Move declaration of `getX()` from `private` to `public`.
2. Add semicolons to the end of every class.
3. Add a return type to `printInfo()`. If you don't want a function to return anything, the return type is `void`. Unless you care declaring a [constructor](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/85-constructors/), which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: I have seperate my woods class and my player class from each other but am still getting the same error where my private variable holds no value when trying to print in another class method

Comment: Some compilers do not allow the initialization while declaration of `x` at at the class level. Try moving `x=10` initialization to a constructor in that case.

Comment: I am trying to set x from user input so putting it in a constructor would not work

Comment: In that case, move setX() to public and make the call to it with `playerObj.setX();`. If that doesn't work, please share what you are seeing more clearly.

Comment: here is a pastebin of the problem I am having. Hopefully, this makes things more clear.      https://pastebin.com/5EUB30Xz

Comment: You are not calling `testObj.setString()` in your pastebin example. If you don't initialize a value (`testObj.x` does not hold any value), you are going to get random characters or in some cases, a crash. Either make a call to setString() before making a call to getString(), or specify a default initialization for `x` with a constructor in `class Test`.

Comment: Yeah i figured it out shortly after I made that post thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working one. It's always a good practice to give a constructor, in order to create an instance with some default values. the following code will work hopefully according to your requirements:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "inTheWoods.h"

int main()
{
    inTheWoods woodsObj;
    woodsObj.printInfo();
    return 0;
}
```

**player.h**

```
#pragma once

class player
{
private:
    int m_x;
public:
    player();
    player(const int& x);

    void setX();            //method for setting X from user input
    const int& getX()const; //Method for retrieving variable
};
```

**player.cpp**

```
#include "player.h"
#include <iostream>

player::player()              // defualt constructor
    :m_x(0) {}

player::player(const int& x)
    :m_x(x) {}                // parameterised

void player::setX()
{
    std::cout << "Set X to a number:" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> m_x;
}

const int& player::getX()const
{
    return m_x;
}
```

**inTheWoods.h**

```
#pragma once

class inTheWoods
{
public:
    inTheWoods();
    ~inTheWoods();
    void printInfo();
};
```

**inTheWoods.cpp**

```
#include "inTheWoods.h"
#include "player.h"
#include <iostream>
inTheWoods::inTheWoods() {}

inTheWoods::~inTheWoods() {}

void inTheWoods::printInfo()
{
    //Player object to access methods in player class
    player playerObj;      // will beinitialized with 0
    player playerObj2(10); // will beinitialized with 10
    std::cout << playerObj.getX() <<std::endl;
    std::cout << playerObj2.getX() <<std::endl;
}
```

**Edit**: Well if you wanna allow the user to set values your `printInfo()` must be as follows:

```
void inTheWoods::printInfo()
{
    //Player object to access methods in player class
    player playerObj;      // will beinitialized with 0
    playerObj.setX();
    std::cout << playerObj.getX() <<std::endl;
}
```